# Can static electricity from carpeting damage a laptop

Tags: static-discharge

Is there any danger of damaging a laptop from static electricity by sliding it across long carpeting? Just using it on long carpeting?

Comment: There's a possibility, sure. I highly doubt anything would happen but I don't think sliding your laptop across long carpeting is something that's going to happen enough for the cumulative risk to kick in :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most danger from static tends to come when the case is off. It is extremely unlikely that simply using a laptop (or probably even sliding it) on long carpet would pose any risk.

If you were to open the case (which likely insulates the motherboard) that would be another story. I wouldn't recommend doing any repairs in that environment. For what it's worth, it was a desktop, but a long time ago I did have a motherboard that biffed it due to static charge that was dissipated while I was working on it.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on who designed and manufactured the laptop.

If the case is well insulated, you shouldn't have problems.

If you open the case and plan to touch the eletronic parts, it's always a problem. Not only for computers, but any eletronic device. And you don't need a carpet to accumulate static electricity, your clothes can do that.